# update database date values format using MY-SQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have date stored in database on date column in `dd-mm-yyyy` format. This column data type is `VARCHAR`. i wanted to convert those stored dates in `yyy-mm-dd` format. i tried using this MYSQL query:

```
UPDATE status SET new_time_creation = STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

but this does not convert the dates properly (eg. 30-05-2016 => 2030-05-20).
please help me with this query or suggest best on even using php to update the date format. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you save such things in a `varchar` ? There are predefined field types for date / time. Simply use them and format the output with PHP. http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.format.php

Comment: @Twinfriends It looks like that is exactly what the OP is trying to do: Convert the wrong type to the correct one.

Comment: @jeroen As far as I understand the question he simply want to change the format how he saves the date, but I can't see any hint that he actually want to change the `type` of the field.

Comment: @Twinfriends Must be my positive outlook that I read it that way; copying the existing data to a new, better format :-)

Comment: @jeroen Well thats possible. We don't know as long as he doesn't answer. :P But may you're right, I don't know.

Comment: @Twinfriends, when i change datatype to date, it will make the dates 0000-00-00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE status SET new_time_creation = STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%m-%Y');
```

try this. You need to format your date `'%d-%m-%Y'` in here. So basically in your code you want the order to be `days-months-years` but you update in the opposite order.

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. *Why* should they use this code? *How* does it solve their problem?

Comment: I updated my answer with a few words in it to explain the problem + the solution. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @pr1nc3 as i said what i want the format to be is Y-m-d

Comment: based on your example you want to convert this date:  _30-05-2016_ so this is the reason your code does not work because this date has the format d/m/Y.

Comment: @pr1nc3 so i want to update this date: 30-05-2016 to 2016-05-30 and i am asking how to do this using query.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE transaction SET new_time_creation = STR_TO_DATE(time_creation, '%Y-%m-%d');`

`STR_TO_DATE` [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

[`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) should work, assuming you have the same format that you specify.

Assuming a basic table as specified below:

```
CREATE TABLE
Demo
(
date VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO `Demo` (`date`) VALUES ('30-05-2016');
```

You can obviously select itself, but you can also format it in whichever format serves your purpose using the [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

```
SELECT
  `date` AS `OriginalFormat`,
  STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `DateFormat`,
  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%m-%d-%Y') AS `CustomFormat`
FROM
  `Demo`
```

Returns:

```
OriginalFormat | DateFormat | CustomFormat
-------------------------------------------
30-05-2016     | 2016-05-30 | 05-30-2016
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85c27c/3